# Error when using onTapLink: argument type can't be assigned 'void Function(String, String, String)'

Tags: flutter, widget

I am trying to implement onTapLink in my Markdown widget (using flutter_markdown library). Everywhere on the internet it tells you to use

```
onTapLink: (url) => launch(url),
```

or

```
onTapLink: (url){
    launch(url);
},
```

but when I do this I get the error

> The argument type 'Future Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, String, String)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I searched 'flutter_markdown' api definition, 'onTapLink' has 3 parameters.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter_markdown/blob/1433d0fcb0cbc775bb258ab3dea720e764e42f92/lib/src/widget.dart#L22

So, although you don't need other parameter, you need to define and use parameter you want.

```
onTapLink: (text, href, title) {
   launch(href);
}
```